# Add new label column based on values in dictionary in python

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

I am new to python I have a data frame with different groups and titles. Now I want to add a column based on median for each group (grp_pred), but I am not sure how I can accomplish this.
This is how my df looks like

```
df
    title   M18-34       V18-34       18-34      25-54       V25-54      M25-54       18-54      V18-54      M18-54
    HEPEN   0.102488    0.200995    0.312438    0.667662    0.334328    0.321393    0.739303    0.380100    0.344279
    MATED   0.151090    0.208723    0.361371    0.733645    0.428349    0.280374    0.880062    0.503115    0.352025
    PEERT   0.098296    0.157929    0.262779    0.624509    0.325033    0.283093    0.717562    0.384010    0.316514
    RZOEK   0.143695    0.336882    0.503607    0.657216    0.414844    0.214674    0.838560    0.548663    0.255410
    ERKEN   0.204918    0.409836    0.631148    0.467213    0.286885    0.163934    0.877049    0.557377    0.303279

median_dict = 

{'18-34': 0.395992275,
 '18-54': 0.79392129200000006,
 '25-54': 0.64958055850000007,
 'M18-34': 0.1171878905,
 'M18-54': 0.27340067349999997,
 'M25-54': 0.23422200100000001,
 'V18-34': 0.2283782815,
 'V18-54': 0.4497918595,
 'V25-54': 0.37749252799999999}
```

required output
so basically I want to compare median values store in the dictionary across each title and then assign to a certain group if the value is equal to that specific median. `e.g say if the median is 0.395992275 then pred_grp is 18-24 and so forth`

```
 df_out
        title   M18-34       V18-34       18-34      25-54       V25-54      M25-54        18-54      V18-54      M18-54  pred_grp
        HEPEN   0.102488    0.200995    0.312438    0.667662    0.334328    0.321393    0.739303    0.380100    0.344279 18-54
        MATED   0.151090    0.208723    0.361371    0.733645    0.428349    0.280374    0.880062    0.503115    0.352025
        PEERT   0.098296    0.157929    0.262779    0.624509    0.325033    0.283093    0.717562    0.384010    0.316514
        RZOEK   0.143695    0.336882    0.503607    0.657216    0.414844    0.214674    0.838560    0.548663    0.255410
        ERKEN   0.204918    0.409836    0.631148    0.467213    0.286885    0.163934    0.877049    0.557377    0.303279
```

How would appreciate your help!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: What would be the expected output? could you show us?

Comment: @anky please see df_out, assuming as an example for first title the median value is   `0.395992275` then pred_grp `is 18-24`. sorry being naive in my explanation though

Comment: Do you mean you calculate median for each row (for all columns) and then compare? For example, the median for the first row is `0.334328` what do you want to return then?

Comment: @anky well, we have a median for each column (different groups) in the dictionary. now based on that I,m going to look at each title row-wise and somehow I can assign that title to the group which has closest to that median (could sort of arbitrary threshold to assign each title to certain group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I understood from comments , you can try creating a df of same structure from the dictionary as the input dataframe and then get the column which has the least difference:

```
u = df.set_index("title")
v = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(median_dict,orient='index').T.reindex(u.columns,axis=1)
df['pred_group'] = (u - v.to_numpy()).idxmin(axis=1).to_numpy()
```

---

```
print(df)

   title    M18-34    V18-34     18-34     25-54    V25-54    M25-54  \
0  HEPEN  0.102488  0.200995  0.312438  0.667662  0.334328  0.321393   
1  MATED  0.151090  0.208723  0.361371  0.733645  0.428349  0.280374   
2  PEERT  0.098296  0.157929  0.262779  0.624509  0.325033  0.283093   
3  RZOEK  0.143695  0.336882  0.503607  0.657216  0.414844  0.214674   
4  ERKEN  0.204918  0.409836  0.631148  0.467213  0.286885  0.163934   

      18-54    V18-54    M18-54 pred_group  
0  0.739303  0.380100  0.344279      18-34  
1  0.880062  0.503115  0.352025      18-34  
2  0.717562  0.384010  0.316514      18-34  
3  0.838560  0.548663  0.255410     M25-54  
4  0.877049  0.557377  0.303279      25-54
```

Comment: I guess this was what need. however, I get this error. `TypeError: reindex() got an unexpected keyword argument "axis"`

Comment: @user3459293 guess this is a version issue, try `reindex(columns=u.columns)` instead of `reindex(u.columns,axis=1)`